TypeORM deprecated issue on NestJS Zero to Hero Udemy's Course
When you go through the course you will find that the way they are using the repository configuration is deprecated, so you will need to find a new way of configuring the Repo so you can continue with the course.
It would be good to mention that the repository is being marked as deprecated which obviously will imply a work around to go through this configuration.
I tried by changing the way that the params are being send to the repository and also using certain specific repository functions, just to check if maybe those were the one deprecated, but none of those are working on there.

In order to properly configure this repository you will need to use a different inject method due to the deprecated of the older one, for this you are going to use dataSource which is the new approach that allows to manage the repository methods,
I will reference this from the typeORM documentation in case some one needed
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm#repository-pattern
on there you will find the details on how to fix this issue and continue with your implementations, feel free to have a check or send me a message if you have any questions.
have fun coding!
